# pyspark to aggregate a column based on the column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe like below
[image]

and I want like below [image]

where based on the value mentioned in the var_col_name that column values need to be checked  and if they are same then it should aggregate and not while they are not the same.
the below code aggregates irrespective the values of next col which is mentioned in var_col_name.

```
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
 from pyspark.sql import functions as F
 from pyspark.sql.window import Window
 # Create a SparkSession
 spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
 # Create the sample data
 data = [
('a', 1, 'text1', 'col1', 'texts1', 'scj', 'dsiul'),
('a', 11, 'text1', 'col1', 'texts1', 'ftjjjjjjj', 'jhkl'),
('b', 2, 'bigger text', 'next_col', 'gfsajh', 'xcj', 'biggest text'),
('b', 21, 'bigger text', 'next_col', 'fghm', 'hjjkl', 'ghjljkk'),
('c', 3, 'soon', 'column', 'szjcj', 'sooner', 'sjdsk')
]
# Create the DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['name', 'id', 'txt', 'var_col_name', 'col1', 'column', 'next_col'])
# Group by 'name' and the column specified in 'var_col_name', and collect the 'id' values into a set
grouped_df = df.groupby('name', 'var_col_name').agg(F.collect_set('id').alias('id_all'))
# Create a window partitioned by 'name' and the column specified in 'var_col_name'
window = Window.partitionBy('name', 'var_col_name')
# Join the original DataFrame with the grouped DataFrame and select the necessary columns
df_agg = df.join(grouped_df, ['name', 'var_col_name'], 'left').select(df['*'], 
F.collect_set('id').over(window).alias('id_all'))
df_agg.show(truncate=False)
```

but the code is generating aggregations for name b for id even though the values "biggest text" not equal to "ghjljkk" (only aggregate if the text is same)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create an intermediate column (called `idx` in the code below) that contains the combination of the value of `var_col_name` and the value of the referenced column for each row:

```
+----+---+-----------+------------+------+---------+------------+---------------------+
|name|id |txt        |var_col_name|col1  |column   |next_col    |idx                  |
+----+---+-----------+------------+------+---------+------------+---------------------+
|a   |1  |text1      |col1        |texts1|scj      |dsiul       |col1_texts1          |
|a   |11 |text1      |col1        |texts1|ftjjjjjjj|jhkl        |col1_texts1          |
|b   |2  |bigger text|next_col    |gfsajh|xcj      |biggest text|next_col_biggest text|
|b   |21 |bigger text|next_col    |fghm  |hjjkl    |ghjljkk     |next_col_ghjljkk     |
|c   |3  |soon       |column      |szjcj |sooner   |sjdsk       |column_sooner        |
+----+---+-----------+------------+------+---------+------------+---------------------+
```

The intermediate column can now be used as partitioning column for an unbounded window:

```python
w=Window.partitionBy('idx').orderBy('id').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df.withColumn('all_cols', F.array([F.struct(F.lit(f'{c}'),
                                   F.col(f'{c}').cast('string')) for c in df.columns])) \
    .withColumn('idx', F.filter('all_cols', 
                                   lambda x: x['col1'] == F.col('var_col_name'))) \
    .withColumn('idx', F.concat_ws('_', F.col('idx')['col1'], 
                                   F.col('idx')['col2'])) \
    .withColumn('id_all', F.collect_list('id').over(w)) \
    .drop('all_cols', 'idx') \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+----+---+-----------+------------+------+---------+------------+-------+
|name|id |txt        |var_col_name|col1  |column   |next_col    |id_all |
+----+---+-----------+------------+------+---------+------------+-------+
|a   |1  |text1      |col1        |texts1|scj      |dsiul       |[1, 11]|
|a   |11 |text1      |col1        |texts1|ftjjjjjjj|jhkl        |[1, 11]|
|c   |3  |soon       |column      |szjcj |sooner   |sjdsk       |[3]    |
|b   |2  |bigger text|next_col    |gfsajh|xcj      |biggest text|[2]    |
|b   |21 |bigger text|next_col    |fghm  |hjjkl    |ghjljkk     |[21]   |
+----+---+-----------+------------+------+---------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: what is col2 here?

Comment: `col1` and `col2` are the two elements of the struct that is created when adding `all_cols`. These are just the default names for a struct.